# Tkinter set window focus and set to foreground after clicking on another window

Tags: python, tkinter

This one has been puzzling me for too much time now, I don't find a way to ensure that a tkinter window is active and on top of the other windows (non-tkinter windows). I managed to recreate the problem with a very simple code. The idea is that during the sleeping time the user clicks on any other window and this seems to screw up the part of the code that should activate the window. If you run the following code and during the sleeping time you don't click anywhere it works fine, but if during that sleeping time you click on any other window the tkinter window appears in a non-active state (or non-foreground). Is there a way to ensures that the tkinter window is active when opened?

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

# Run code and click on any other window during the 3 seconds waiting time
time.sleep(3)

root = tk.Tk()
root.lift()
root.attributes("-topmost", True)
root.focus_force()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. The window pops into foreground with no issue. Did you test it with exact code you provided?

Comment: Did you run the code and then immediately clicked on any window before the window appears? Yes, I did test it with the code I provided. I can make a GIF tomorrow. The window does popup in the foreground yes, but not in an active state. I need it in an active state because I want to start writing into a widget immediately, without activating the window bu clicking on it. It is actually quite annoying because most of times I click on my text editor during those 3 seconds and then, thinking that I'm already typing into the window, I start typing and I am instead typing in my text editor

Comment: Yes, I clicked another window immediately after running the code. What OS are you running?

Comment: Running on Windows 10 - 64 bit.

Comment: Does it pop up in an active state or just on the foreground but not active (by active I mean selected, basically the window title "tk" is greyed)?

Comment: Oh, you're right, it's not active. I tried a couple of things and couldn't get it working...

Comment: You don't know how much stuff I tried.. It is so annoying.. I even have a piece of code using the ctypes module that restores a window that has been minimized and it makes it active that runs perfectly fine when I use it as a callback function with a button but it doesn't work if I use it as callback function of the tkinter after method.. It is so weird..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222200/discussion-between-bozo-stojkovic-and-francesco).